# Probability question. Method of Maximum Likelihood

Tags: probability

> According to genetic theory, blood types **MM**, **NM** and **NN** should occur in a very large population with relative frequencies $\theta^{2},\ 2\theta(1-\theta),$ and $(1-\theta)^{2}$, where $\theta$ is the (unknown) gene frequency.
>
> (a) Suppose that, in a random sample of size $n$ from the population, there are $x_{1},\ x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$ individuals of the three types respectively. Find an expression for $\hat{\theta}$
>
> **Answer: $\hat{\theta} =\dfrac{(2x_{1}+x{2})}{2n}=0.55  $**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_1 = \theta^2$, $p_2 = 2\theta(1-\theta)$ and $p_3 = 1 - p_1-p_2 = (1-\theta)^2$. If the population is very large then the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is approximately trinomial with parameters $(n,p_1,p_2)$, i.e.
$$
        P[X_i = x_i]
\approx \frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!(n-x_1-x_2)!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}(1-p_1-p_2)^{n-x_1-x_2}.
$$
So the log likelihood function is approximately
$$
  \log L(\theta \mid x_1,x_2,x_3)
= \log\left( \frac{ n! }{x!x_2!(n-x_1 - x_2)!} \right) + \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \log p_i.
$$
Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ gives
\begin{align}
   \frac{d}{d\theta} \log L(\theta)
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{x_i}{p_i} \frac{d}{d\theta} p_i \\
&= \frac{2x_1 \theta}{\theta^2} + \frac{(2 - 4\theta)x_2}{2\theta(1-\theta)} + 
   \frac{-2(1-\theta)(n-x_1-x_2)}{(1-\theta)^2} \\
&= \frac{2x_1 }{\theta} + \frac{(1 - 2\theta)x_2}{\theta(1-\theta)} + 
   \frac{-2(n-x_1-x_2)}{(1-\theta)} \\
&= \frac{2(1-\theta)x_1 + (1 - 2\theta)x_2-2\theta(n-x_1-x_2)}{\theta(1-\theta)}  \\
&= \frac{2x_1 + x_2-2\theta n}{\theta(1-\theta)},
\end{align}
and setting this equal to $0$ gives
$$
  \hat\theta
= \frac{2x_1 + x_2}{2n}.
$$

Comment: @Wmmoreno No problem!