# Statistics Question. Method of Maximum Likelihood, Finding MLE's

Tags: probability, statistics

This is my first ever question. Details on what/why you are doing what you are doing would be amazing. I saw a question with the same problem but did not understand the answer NOR was part (b) asked about. (Here is the link to the other question [Probability question. Method of Maximum Likelihood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792389/probability-question-method-of-maximum-likelihood)) **I was wondering why can't I just use: "$Likelihood = {(θ^2)}^{x_1} * {[2θ(1-θ)]}^{x_2} * [(1-θ)^2]^{x_3}$", then take my log-Likelihood, score, and information functions from there? When I did it my way I ended up with $MLE = \hatθ = (-4x_1-x_2) / [4(x_3-x_1)]$.** However my answer was wrong (I posted the answers at the end). Thanks so much!!!

Here is the question:

According to genetic theory, blood types MM, NM and NN should occur in a very large population with relative frequencies $θ^2, 2θ(1−θ)$, and $(1−θ)^2$, where $θ$ is the (unknown) gene frequency.

(a) Suppose that, in a random sample of size n from the population, there are $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ individuals of the three types respectively. Find an expression for $\hatθ$ (the Maximum Likelihood Estimate)

(b) The observed frequencies in a sample of size 100 were 32, 46, and 22, respectively. Compute $\hatθ$ (the MLE) and the estimated expected frequencies for the three blood types under the model.

**Answers:** $MLE=\hatθ=(2x_1+x_2)/2n=0.55$

exp. freq. 30.25, 49.50, 20.25

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.stackexchange.  You seem like you have a well-thought out question but the symbols you've used might be a little difficult for users to decipher in helping you answer your question.  I'd highly recommend checking out this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help your question be a little clearer.

Comment: Never ever computed any MLE? How did you proceed then?

Comment: @Mnifldz Thanks! I believe I have them all fixed. Do you know how to do this question?

Comment: @Did I have computed MLE's...? Never said I haven't, but I am having difficulty with this question.

Comment: Show how you differentiate the log-likelihood, the error is probably there.

Comment: @Did WOW. Such a dumb mistake... :( But thank you for the prompt. I think my stress and lack of sleep did not do me any favors.